# DIY hologram experiments split screen

Tags: rendering, unreal, viewport

I am currently experimenting with the DIY holograms. Does anyone know to split my windows into 4 perpendicular identical displays like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YWTtCsvgvg) but for Windows?

I am using Unreal Engine & I want it to make something like [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/120036/39518) but the user should be able to rotate the camera.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [How to render multiple projections of an object](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/120036/39518)? If you want specific guidance, you should mention what technology stack you're using to build your game, and what you've tried so far based on your research and experimentation.

Comment: i am using unreal engine and yes what i have in mind is somehow like the forum you linked but a bit different i want the user to be able to rotate the cameras himself

Comment: Be sure to edit your question to include those details. There's nothing in the linked solution that would prevent the user from rotating the cameras, so you can try to apply the same strategy in Unreal.

Comment: thanks for your help i am pretty new to game design